# Is there any case where it's valid to unlock then lock an unlocked mutex, while another thread tries to lock it with a lock_guard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, stdthread

I apologize for the poor title, just looking for someone to confirm Im not crazy.

I recently stumbled across some code that has been in use for years without anyone complaining. The reason I was looking into it was because I was getting this error while heavily modifying this codebase:

```
pthread_mutex_lock.c:90: ___pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
```

After some digging, I found a pretty weird (to me) use of a mutex. In essence:

1. Two threads are spawned and detached from the main thread (Both threads are in the same .cpp file, and share a globally declared mutex)
2. In the one that seems to be hit first, the mutex is unlocked and then locked with a 10us pause in a loop, to "allow the other thread to process messages" according to a comment
3. The thread that would likely get hit second (spawned first, but waits to receive data) has a case in a switch statement that locks the mutex with a `lock_guard`

**I believe this is undefined behavior in multiple ways, but I am getting some pushback in saying that it should be changed as I am struggling to reproduce this exact error consistently and minimally.**

I assume this is intended to operate such that the mutex is unlocked first by the looping thread (from an unlocked state, no data for the `lock_guard` thread to process yet), then locked, and would spend most of its time locked, while the `lock_guard` occasionally tries to lock, and has to wait for the loop to unlock it, at which point it can process its data, `lock_guard` goes out of scope, and the lock is returned to the looping thread.

What I think is causing my error is; The `lock_guard` thread gets data sooner than expected with my modifications, and so the `lock_guard` case is triggered, and then the looping thread tries to unlock another threads mutex.

I am looking for:

- Confirmation that it is UB to declare a mutex, then unlock it without it being locked
- Confirmation that it is UB if the looping thread unlocks the mutex while it is held by the `lock_guard`
- Confirmation of my assumption of what is causing my error (I basically already know the first two from references, but want to be sure Im not missing some big brain way of doing things I am unaware of)
- Maybe a better way to do this, I would assume this could be fixed just by locking the mutex outside of the loop first?

I have searched the codebase and the mutex is only used 4 times that I can see: When it is declared, when it is used in the `lock_guard` and when it is unlocked, then locked so my while my MRE is short, I think it basically has everything it needs. to demonstrate how this mutex is being used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>

std::mutex data_mtx;

void lg_thread(){
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(data_mtx);

  usleep(10e6);
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){
  std::thread t1(lg_thread);

  usleep(10000);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    data_mtx.unlock();
    usleep(500);
    data_mtx.lock();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [std::mutex::unlock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) _"...The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined..."_. So the first `data_mtx.unlock()` in `main` is UB.

Comment: Does the first thread not lock the mutex before unlocking it?

Comment: @user253751 not that I was able to tell. As far as I am aware it would unlock first which we've just been lucky enough is 'friendly' UB in that it seemingly has just been doing nothing, or it would (try to, from another thread) unlock a mutex locked by the lock guard and cause the assertion error I was seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am looking for:
>
> - Confirmation that it is UB to declare a mutex, then unlock it without it being locked

Unlocking a `mutex` that is not currently locked/owned by the calling thread is *undefined behavior*, yes.

> - Confirmation that it is UB if the looping thread unlocks the mutex while it is held by the `lock_guard`

Yes, it is UB. See above.

> - Confirmation of my assumption of what is causing my error (I basically already know the first two from references, but want to be sure Im not missing some big brain way of doing things I am unaware of)

See above.

> - Maybe a better way to do this

Consider using a `std::condition_variable` instead to coordinate the threads.

> I would assume this could be fixed just by locking the mutex outside of the loop first?

Yes.  That way, if `main()` locks the `mutex` first then the `lock_guard` will block waiting for `main()` to unlock it, and if the `lock_guard` locks the `mutex` first then `main()` will block waiting for the `lock_guard` to unlock it.  As it should be.

Comment: Worked with a guy who liked to do this sort of witchery and I'm glad I bailed from that job before he retired. I wasted way too much time trying to track down the other end of his mutex locks. Sometimes they were not only unlocked in different threads, but in different software modules. A couple times in <expletive deleted>ing ISRs. There was no way on God's green earth I wanted to be stuck maintaining that <expletive deleted>. Don't be that guy.

Comment: Quite concise, thank you for the suggestion as well.

Comment: @DouglasB, do consider that `condition_variable` suggestion carefully.  Done right, it can both allow you to drop the first thread's `usleep()`, *and* allow you to ensure that the second thread gets a chance to run.  Alternatively, replacing the mutex with a `std::binary_semaphore` could possibly provide the same benefit.